# Feeding a Sparse Data into Tensorflow Estimator's Fit

Tags: python, tensorflow

I converted a label into sparse a sparse label tuple (indices, values, shape). However, when I feed it to the classifier, I encounter this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 23, in <module>
    classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=sparse_y_train, batch_size=128, steps=10)
  File "...tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 464, in fit
    SKCompat(self).fit(x, y, batch_size, steps, max_steps, monitors)
  File "...tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 1429, in fit
    epochs=None)
  File "...tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 139, in _get_input_fn
    epochs=epochs)
  File "...tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_io\data_feeder.py", line 151, in setup_train_data_feeder
    x, y, n_classes, batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, epochs=epochs)
  File "...tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_io\data_feeder.py", line 326, in __init__
    if y_is_dict else check_array(y, y.dtype))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

How do I feed a sparse tuple into the classifier?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear says 'tuple' has no attribute of 'dtype'. You probably want convert your label as a numpy array (with just values)?

Comment: I fed the dense labels into the fit function instead of the sparse ones and did the conversion within the model_function. However, I'm facing this error discussed in this question now: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201725/converting-tensor-to-a-sparsetensor-for-ctc-loss?noredirect=1#comment83393474_48201725