# ValueError from tensorflow estimator RNNClassifier with gcloud ml-engine job

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, gcloud, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I am working on the task.py file for submitting a gcloud MLEngine job. Previously I was using tensorflow.estimator.DNNClassifier successfully to submit jobs with my data (which consists solely of 8 columns of sequential numerical data for cryptocurrency prices & volume; no categorical).

I have now switched to the tensorflow contrib estimator RNNClassifier. This is my current code for the relevant portion:

```
def get_feature_columns():
  return [
      tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature, shape=(1,))
      for feature in column_names[:len(column_names)-1]
  ]

def build_estimator(config, learning_rate, num_units):
  return tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier(
    sequence_feature_columns=get_feature_columns(),
    num_units=num_units,
    cell_type='lstm',
    rnn_cell_fn=None,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    config=config)

estimator = build_estimator(
    config=run_config,
    learning_rate=args.learning_rate,
    num_units=[32, 16])

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

However, I'm getting the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: All feature_columns must be of type _SequenceDenseColumn. You can wrap a sequence_categorical_column with an embedding_column or indicator_column. Given (type <class 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2.NumericColumn'>): NumericColumn(key='LTCUSD_close', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None)
```

I don't understand this, as the data is not categorical.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ben7 pointed out [sequence_feature_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNClassifier#__init__) accepts columns like [sequence_numeric_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/feature_column/sequence_numeric_column). However, according to the documentation, [RNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNClassifier#class_rnnclassifier) sequence_feature_columns expects SparseTensors and sequence_numeric_column is a dense tensor. This seems to be contradictory.

Here is a workaround I used to solve this issue (I took the to_sparse_tensor function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203570/7517757)):

```py
def to_sparse_tensor(dense):

    # sequence_numeric_column default is float32
    zero = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32) 

    where = tf.not_equal(dense, zero)
    indices = tf.where(where)
    values = tf.gather_nd(dense, indices)

    return tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, tf.shape(dense, out_type=tf.dtypes.int64))

def get_feature_columns():
  return [
      tf.feature_column.sequence_numeric_column(feature, shape=(1,), normalizer_fn=to_sparse_tensor)
      for feature in column_names[:len(column_names)-1]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you got this error because you use a numeric feature column whereas this kind of estimator can only accept sequence feature columns as you can see it on the [init function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNClassifier#__init__).

So, instead of using numeric column you have to use [sequence_numeric_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/feature_column/sequence_numeric_column).

Comment: Changing *tf.feature_column.numeric_column* to *tf.contrib.feature_column.sequence_numeric_column* results in: "TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor."