# How to use tensorflow sequence_numeric_column with an RNNClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I was looking throw the tensorflow contrib API and I wanted to use the [RNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNClassifier#__init__) available with Tensorflow 1.13. Contrary to non sequence estimators, this one needs sequence feature columns only. However I was not able to make it work on a toy dataset. I keep getting an error while using [sequence_numeric_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/feature_column/sequence_numeric_column).

Here is the structure of my toy dataset:

```
idSeq,kind,label,size
0,0,dwarf,117.6
0,0,dwarf,134.4
0,0,dwarf,119.0
0,1,human,168.0
0,1,human,145.25
0,2,elve,153.9
0,2,elve,218.49999999999997
0,2,elve,210.9
1,0,dwarf,166.6
1,0,dwarf,168.0
1,0,dwarf,131.6
1,1,human,150.5
1,1,human,208.25
1,1,human,210.0
1,2,elve,199.5
1,2,elve,161.5
1,2,elve,197.6
```

where idSeq allow us to see which rows belong to which sequence.
I want to predict the "kind" column thanks to the "size" column.

Below there is my code about make my RNN training on my dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

dataframe = pd.read_csv("data_rnn.csv")
dataframe_test = pd.read_csv("data_rnn_test.csv")


train_x = dataframe
train_y = dataframe.loc[:,(["kind"])]


size_feature_col = tf.contrib.feature_column.sequence_numeric_column('size ')


estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier(
    sequence_feature_columns=[size_feature_col ],
    num_units=[32, 16],
    cell_type='lstm',
    model_dir=None,
    n_classes=3,
    optimizer='Adagrad'
)



def make_dataset(
    batch_size, 
    x, 
    y=None, 
    shuffle=False, 
    shuffle_buffer_size=1000,
    shuffle_seed=1):
    """
    An input function for training, evaluation or prediction.

    Parameters
    ----------------------
    batch_size: integer
        the size of the batch to use for the training of the neural network
    x: pandas dataframe 
        dataframe that contains the features of the samples to study
    y: pandas dataframe or array (Default: None)
        dataframe or array that contains the values to predict of the samples
        to study. If none, we want a dataset for evaluation or prediction.
    shuffle: boolean (Default: False)
        if True, we shuffle the elements of the dataset
    shuffle_buffer_size: integer (Default: 1000)
        if we shuffle the elements of the dataset, it is the size of the buffer
        used for it.
    shuffle_seed : integer
        the random seed for the shuffling

    Returns
    ---------------------
    dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next(): Tensor
        a nested structure of tf.Tensors containing the next element of the 
        dataset to study
    """

    def input_fn():
        if y is not None:
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y))
        else:
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(x))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(
                buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size,
                seed=shuffle_seed).batch(batch_size).repeat()
        else:
            dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
        return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return input_fn



batch_size = 50
random_seed = 1


input_fn_train = make_dataset(
            batch_size=batch_size, 
            x=train_x, 
            y=train_y, 
            shuffle=True, 
            shuffle_buffer_size=len(train_x),
            shuffle_seed=random_seed)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=5000)
```

But I only got the following error :

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 125, in <module>
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=5000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 358, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1124, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1154, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1112, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/rnn.py", line 512, in _model_fn
    config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/rnn.py", line 332, in _rnn_model_fn
    logits, sequence_length_mask = logit_fn(features=features, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/rnn.py", line 226, in rnn_logit_fn
    features=features, feature_columns=sequence_feature_columns)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/feature_column/python/feature_column/sequence_feature_column.py", line 120, in sequence_input_layer
    trainable=trainable)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/feature_column/python/feature_column/sequence_feature_column.py", line 496, in _get_sequence_dense_tensor
    sp_tensor, default_value=self.default_value)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 1432, in sparse_tensor_to_dense
    sp_input = _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_input)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 68, in _convert_to_sparse_tensor
    raise TypeError("Input must be a SparseTensor.")
TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.
```

So I don't understand what I've done wrong because on the documentation, it is written that we have to give a sequence column to the RNNEstimator. They do not say anything about giving sparse tensor.

Thanks in advance for your help and advices.

Comment: First of all, 'size' column does not look like a sequence. tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse can be useful to convert to sparse tensor.

Comment: The TypeError can be resolved as per this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527650/2295722 , but I expect that this only brings you one step further until the next exception..