# Is there a way to output a sparse tensor using tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sparse-matrix

I'd like to train a model for semantic segmentation, so the output tensor contains a lot of zeros. I created a tf.data dataset which returns a tensorflow sparse tensor containing the output masks to consume less RAM while training but when I try tf.keras.fit, I get

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("cond_2/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=int64, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0), values=Tensor("cond_2/Identity_2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0), dense_shape=Tensor("stack:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int64, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I tried using tf.sparse operations in a debug loss like this

```
def test_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.sparse.reduce_sum(y_true) - tf.sparse.reduce_sum(y_pred)
```

but the error is now

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'indices'
```

I guess the model's output is supposed to be a Tensor object and this error happens at the compilation of the model. 
Is there any way to force a tf.keras model output to be a sparse tensor ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201725/converting-tensor-to-a-sparsetensor-for-ctc-loss

Answer (score 0):

Please refer sample code to convert tensor to sparse tensor

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Make a tensor from a constant
a = np.reshape(np.arange(24), (3, 4, 2))
a_t = tf.constant(a)
# Find indices where the tensor is not zero
idx = tf.where(tf.not_equal(a_t, 0))
# Make the sparse tensor
# Use tf.shape(a_t, out_type=tf.int64) instead of a_t.get_shape()
# if tensor shape is dynamic
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(idx, tf.gather_nd(a_t, idx), a_t.get_shape())
```